# Create "title" attribute on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Part of my HTML Code is created according to my javascript code, more precisely the attributes of tag `<a>` (`href` and `title`).
I'm trying to create a HTML `title` inside `<a>` so I can have the mouseover effect, and present the Title and Description.
According to my javascript code, `myTitle` array will have the Title for every image, and will be displayed according to its position...

HTML CODE

```
<a href="../test/top.php?title=sample1.mp4" title="Título 1 Descript 1">
    <img style="z-index: 20; position: absolute; left: 365px; top: 63px; width: 189px;" src="spiral/sample1.jpg">
</a>
<a href="../test/top.php?title=sample2.mp4" title="Título 1 Descript 1" >
    <img style="z-index: 17; position: absolute; left: 674px; top: 60px; width: 155px;" src="spiral/sample2.jpg">
</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var myTitle = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"];
var myDescr = ["Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3"];

$('img').wrap(function(){
return $('<a>').attr({
    href:
    '../test/top.php?title=' + this.src, title: myTitle[0] + "\n" + myDescr[0]
    })
});
```

The problem now, is that I can't create a `for` cycle inside the `attr` and so I can't print myTitle[0], myTitle[1] and myTitle[2] for every image...

Any ideas you can I bypass this problem?

Note that the `myTitle` an `myDescr` arrays are variable, and IMAGES CAN BE REPEATED...

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net to reproduction.

Comment: the `.wrap(function(index)` gets the index passed in as an argument http://api.jquery.com/wrap/#wrap-functionindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, using the index argument in [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) callback function.

```
$('img').wrap(function (i) {

    return $('<a>').attr({
        href:
            '../test/top.php?title=' + this.src,
        title: myTitle[i] + "\n" + myDescr[i]
    })
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tX8Zf/)

> .wrap( function(index) )

If you want the title/desc to repeat through for repeating images try this way.

```
var myTitle = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"];
var myDescr = ["Desc 1", "Desc 2", "Desc 3"];

$('img').wrap(function (i) {
    var title = myTitle.shift(); //Get the top
    myTitle.push(title); //push back for cycle
    var descr = myDescr.shift();//Get the top
    myDescr.push(descr);//push back for cycle

    return $('<a>').attr({
        href:
            '../test/top.php?title=' + this.src,
        title: title + "\n" + descr
    })
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qFqg7/)

Comment: nice one - I forgot that `.wrap` can also take a callback function.

Comment: @Alnitak Infact OP is using the callback but not utilizing the argument.

Comment: @zppinto It does not in the fiddle. Something else with your code probably. Can you replicate it in the fiddle. Also what is undefined?

Comment: @zppinto Not sure what you are saying but if you want to title and desc to repeat for images you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/qFqg7/

Comment: Your sure! Is that what I'm talking about :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

How about using `.each()`?

```
$('img').each(function(i) {
    $(this).wrap(function(){
        return $('<a>').attr({
            href: '../test/top.php?title=' + this.src, title: myTitle[i] + "\n" + myDescr[i]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why but `title` always comes up with "undefined"

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other `img` elements on the page?  The way you have this set up, the order of the elements is very important

Comment: I think that's the problem! I have more... And I forgot to mention that the images can be repeated, and so I can't use it this way :(

Comment: Probably need to rethink how you're generating the page :/

Comment: The problem is in the repeated images... For those the `title` and `description` came as "undefined"!